# How to create three columns from selected posts

Tags: posts, columns

I would like to create a three columns with 3 selected posts. They must include image and title. Like this [http://i.imgur.com/tXg0bv3.png](https://i.imgur.com/tXg0bv3.png)
How to create it in CSS and HTML?
This is very important for me, I can't find something like that. Thanks.

I'm sorry, I did not mention. This columns must be outside the loop. This is a code for post outside the loop:

```
<?php
$recent = new WP_Query();
$recent->query('showposts=1');
if($recent->have_posts()) : while($recent->have_posts()): $recent->the_post();
?>
<div class="post_image_th">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('mainImageCropped'); ?>
</div>
<div class="post_content_spot">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<ul>
<li class="user"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></li>
<li class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link('0 comments &#187;', '1 comment &#187;', '% comments &#187;'); ?></li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p> Nothing find </p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: You can have more than one loop on a page. Run a custom loop for the 3 columns and then run your main page loop below that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that :

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$args   = array('posts_per_page' => 3);
$recent = new WP_Query($args);
if($recent->have_posts()) : while($recent->have_posts()): $recent->the_post();
$i++;
?>

<div class="post-in-column">
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>

<?php echo ($i % 3 == 0) ? '<div class="clear"></div>' : ''; ?>
```

No news.

Then a little bit of CSS :

```
.clear {clear:both;}
.post-in-column {float:left; width: 33%/* maybe you'll need to set fixed width */; }
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mention. This columns must be outside the loop. I add code to my question.

Comment: No problem just replace with your own Query.

Comment: Thank You very much, but now my posts, display like this: http://i.imgur.com/5d6QVk8.png (1-1-1) I want (1-2-3). Because I use additional loop I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can anyone help? ;)

Comment: I've edited code. Do not use showposts it 's deprecated, replace it with `posts_per_page`

Answer (score 0):

You might not have expected this kind of solution but it is worth knowing that there is also a front end solution for this kind of problem.

The css3 spec have a new feature called `column-count`, which will automatically render your text in multiple columns

Here is a simple example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp)

```
div
{
column-count:3;
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Here is [another](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/)

I know this only works in modern browsers, but people have started using it already!

And good news there already  a fallback jquery plugin for this called  [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/)